# How can I permanently associate tc qdisc commands with a particular interface?

Tags: networking, openvpn, bandwidth, tc

I need to use a `tc qdisc` command to limit bandwidth usage on an interface created by `openvpn`. This works great when I run the command manually but occasionally the connection drops or restarts and this appears to cancel or deactivate the previously applied bandwidth settings. Is there a way to make a `tc qdisc` command apply permanently (or at least until I choose to cancel it) on a particular interface in such a way that any time that interface is up, my bandwidth settings will apply? I need something like the `firewall-cmd` permanent flag that makes the settings stick.

The command I'm currently using looks something like this:

```
tc qdisc add dev tun0 tbf rate 1mbit latency...
```

where `tun0` is the interface name created by `openvpn`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`openvpn` has an option called `--up cmd` which runs `cmd` whenever the VPN connection is first established, and an `--up-restart` option which tells `openvpn` to also run the `--up` command when a connection is restarted.

You can write a script which contains your `tc qdisc ...` command, make it executable with `chmod +x`, and then add `--up /path/to/my/script --up-restart` to the `openvpn` command line.

Alternatively, the `cmd` can be a properly quoted string containing the entire command and all its arguments.  e.g.

```
openvpn ...  --up 'tc qdisc ...' --up-restart ...
```

This is possibly simpler, but a script is more flexible and makes it easier to do more than one thing when the connection is established.

BTW, there is also a `--down cmd` option which is used to run scripts or other programs whenever a VPN disconnects.

See `man openvpn` for more details about `--up` and `--down` and related options.

---

Note: it is possible that your Linux distribution may already make use of this feature, and may have a directory where you can just create a script to have it automatically run whenever the VPN is first established or restarted.  Check the documentation for your distribution's openvpn package.  If it does something like that, then follow the instructions there.  If not, use the `--up` option as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm on CentOS and was able to place an up.sh script in /etc/openvpn and reference it by adding "up /etc/openvpn/up.sh" from the .conf file in the same directory. It was also necessary to add "script-security 2" to the .conf file. It seems to be working and doing what I want. Thanks!